# How to start writing a smart contract in eWASM?

Tags: contract-development, ewasm, wasm

There are many tools and repositories under https://github.com/ewasm

What are the main steps to writing a smart contract in eWASM?  What are the main components involved?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write contract in eWASM. Just write it using solidity, and it will be converted to EVM bytecode, then eWASM.

As I know so far, the eWASM is only available on Kovan testnet, so you may need to use parity to test it out if you're interested.

Comment: Some of the steps you have written at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47759/how-to-run-ewasm-on-v8 can help improve this answer.