# Is there a "Hello world" smart contract in ewasm?

Tags: ewasm

Is there any ewasm smart contract for testing?

The example contracts of parity cannot be deployed due to exceeding block gas 
https://github.com/paritytech/pwasm-tutorial/

Comment: What is ewasm smart contract?

Comment: Ewasm only is supported in kovan testnet https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47485.

Comment: @Ismael Yes. I would like to deploy an example smart contract to Kovan testnet but I am unable to deploy any examples  https://github.com/paritytech/pwasm-tutorial/

Answer (score 5):

The de-facto Hello World contract is WRC-20, which is essentially a subset of ERC20 implemented in Ewasm.It is implemented in a few languages as an example.

In C: https://github.com/ewasm/wrc20-examples/blob/3553ea7c87fcb1012e6d76c28ba0cbe878fe55c2/C/wrc20.c

In Rust, also implementing all of WRC20: https://github.com/hugo-dc/wrc20-rust/blob/master/src/ewasm_token.rs

Apologies for that, we really need to store the examples centrally. Hopefully this helps.

To clarify some other misconceptions: Kovan is now sunsetted, and also it implements Parity Wasm (Pwasm) rather than Ewasm. The Ewasm testnet is available here: https://ewasm.ethereum.org